# plot choropleth using google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

I have a data set of `{zip code, value}` pairs and would like to visualize  it on a map.

Let's say my data set structure is:

```
{
"pageType": "ZIP",
"ZIP": {
    "90638": {
        "OVERALL": "320.00"
    },
    "75594": {
        "OVERALL": "2985.02"
    },
    "10997": {
        "OVERALL": "55554.2"
    }
  }
}
```

I want to plot this set of zip codes on Google Maps using a colored area corresponding to the zip codes, like on the screenshot below.

[d3js](https://d3js.org/) or [highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) will not work because they have a location file for a country for plotting the graph. In my case I want to implement it for any country in the world, so I need to use Google Maps.

Any idea
[image: heatmap]

Comment: Do you need the color of the zip area to correspond to the value you have for a given zip code? Do you need the zip code areas to be clearly visible or do you simply want a heatmap* of all the values? *https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-heatmap

Comment: the example you gave uses lat long.no i dont need to show the area. If i am able to plot markers for corresponding area thats also enough.

Comment: Do you need to surface the value of the "OVERALL" variable? How do you want to do it?

Comment: no not neccesary, Is there any way to plot via zip code and value.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using [OpenStreetMap shapefiles](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Shapefiles) or perhaps their [Nominatim service](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim) to get polygon data for administrative boundaries?  This is way, way easier than trying to wring that data out of Google Maps, and you can then display it however you want.

For instance, here are the [state boundaries of Gujarat in GeoJSON format](https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q=gujarat&format=json&polygon_geojson=1), and the [equivalent HTML view](https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/ui/details.html?osmtype=R&osmid=1949080) from the Nominatim service.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is possible, since if you type-in a zip cod to Google Maps, it returns the area of the zipcode, however it seems like there are no "Google Zipcode API" that you can apply directly via Google Javascript API to draw the color zipcode area, which means that you will need to create the zipcode table by yourself or from somewhere else. Please see [How do I do a simple zip code map showing boundaries with Google Maps API V3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12782034/how-do-i-do-a-simple-zip-code-map-showing-boundaries-with-google-maps-api-v3)   (An old discuss here)

In sum, I would suggest you to look up the fusion table layer for color-zone of zip code, and then the value will be easy to assign a marker on Google Maps Javascript API.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the **[Geocoder library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding)** of Google Maps. It can resolve the zip and town pair to a map position.

I added the country element for get more accurate results.

On this example you can create markers using zip codes. You should add a bit more code to show the value of each zip code you have on your data set.

```js
/*
 * declare map as a global variable
 */
var map;

/*
 * use google maps api built-in mechanism to attach dom events
 */
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", function() {

  /*
   * create map
   */
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_div"), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(35.38905, -40.078125),
    zoom: 1,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  /*
   * create infowindow (which will be used by markers)
   */
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  /*
   * marker creater function (acts as a closure for html parameter)
   */
  function createMarker(options, html) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker(options);
    if (html) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(html);
        infoWindow.open(options.map, this);
      });
    }
    return marker;
  }

  function createMarkerZip(zipcode, town, country) {
    var direction = zipcode + ',' + town + ',' + country;
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    geocoder.geocode({
        'address': direction
      },
      function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          createMarker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(
              results[0].geometry.location.lat(),
              results[0].geometry.location.lng()),
            map: map
          }, direction);
        } else {
          console.log("Zip: " + zipcode + ", town: " + town + " not found :-(");
        }
      }
    );
  }

  createMarkerZip('46003', 'valencia', 'spain');
  createMarkerZip("nv 89821", "crescent valley", "usa");
  createMarkerZip("va 22310", "alexandria", "usa");

});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&amp;sensor=false"></script>
<div id="map_div" style="height: 400px;"></div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/netvicious/4m2vf0dh/

**Note**: *You should add your key to the Google Maps script to make it work.*

Comment: jsfiddle link broken

Comment: Fixed, thanks, the problem it's Google Maps now requires the use of one API and it doesn't works on jsfiddle. But if you place the correct call to the js with a valid key the code will work ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you are not married to Google Maps, you should look at [Leaflet - an open-source JavaScript library for mobile-friendly interactive maps](http://leafletjs.com/examples.html) Here is the link for the [Interactive Choropleth Map](http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth.html) where it appears they have done most of the work for you. From the tutorial: "*This is a case study of creating a colorful interactive choropleth map of US States Population Density with the help of GeoJSON and some custom controls...*" The features, tutorials and code examples are extensive. I hope this helps.